# How to pass data correctly from a Java servlet to an HTML file with VueJS

Tags: javascript, java, html, vue.js

So essentially I am trying to pass JSON from a servlet to a HTML page that is using VueJS as well.

This is how I am going about forwarding the json data from the servlet:

```
    List<Projects> list = projectInfo.getProjects();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(list);
    req.setAttribute("projects", json);
    req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/projectMaint.html").forward(req, resp);
```

So after this, I am attempting to run Vue in the HTML page like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = new Vue({
el: '#test-app',
data: {
    json: projects
}
})
</script>
```

However I am not sure how to "grab" the json data attribute that I am passing. I know the servlet is running each time but I am getting confused on how to grab it. This may be trivial and basic but any help is appreciated.

Comment: This: "_However I am not sure how to "grab" the json data attribute that I am passing._" - you can't (unless projectMaint is actually a JSP). You either 1. have to include the data into the page using a templating system on the server OR 2. use a separate end-point and second request for requesting/retrieving the data for your Vue app.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you can make your html pages to jsp that way you can bind the information that is provided from the server side using component props and expression language of jsp for example:

```
<testApp project-list="${projects}"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
var app = new Vue({
el: '#test-app',
props: {
projectList: String
},
data: {
    json: projects
}
})
</script>
```

after this you can bind the props to data if you want or directly use
`this.projectList`
Or you can make a another endpoint to just get the json